# How to use Cayley-Hamiltonian theorem in proving upper bound on linear space $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, characteristic-functions

If $W = span(I,A,A^1,A^2, \dots)$. What is the upper bound on dimension of $W$? All matrices are $n \times n$.

I know that the dim($W$) $\leq n$, by the Cayley-Hamiltonian theorem. However, I don't see *how* the Cayley-Hamiltonian (C-H) theorem is used to show this. From what I understand, the C-H theorem says once you get the characteristic polynomial equation for matrix $M$, $p(\lambda)$, then $p(M) =$ the zero matrix. I'm not sure how C-H can be used in showing that $dim(W) \leq n$.

Second question:

If $A=$ zero matrix, then would the dimension of $W = 1$ or $2$?

Comment: When $A = 0$, the vector space $W$ is the span of the single matrix $I$, so its dimension is ...?

Comment: @Yuval 1, correct?

Comment: That's what I think as well.

Comment: If $I$ would have been $\left(\begin{array}{cc}a & 0 \\0 & b\end{array}\right)$, would the dimension of $W$ now be 2 (with A being the zero matrix)?

Comment: even if $a \neq b$? Isn't the dimension of the new I, call it $I' = a\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\0 & 0\end{array}\right) + b\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 0 \\0 & 1\end{array}\right)$. Doesn't $I'$ have dimension 2?

Comment: The dimension of $W$ equals the degree of the minimal polynomial of $A$. The dimension of the span of a single matrix $M$ is at most $1$, so in particular the dimension of the span of $I'$ is at most $1$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: The Cayley-Hamilton theorem implies that $A^n$ is a linear combination of $I,A,A^2,\ldots,A^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that

$A = [a_{ij}], \;\; 1 \le i, j \le n, \tag{1}$

where the $a_{ij} \in \Bbb F$, $\Bbb F$ some field; then a moment's reflection reveals that $W$ may be expressed as the space of all polynomials in $A$, that is

$W = \Bbb F[A]. \tag{2}$

Suppose $A \ne 0$;  then characteristic polynomial  of $A$, $p(x)  \ne 0$.   Now for $f(x) \in \Bbb F[x]$, by the Euclidean algotithm applied to $\Bbb F[x]$ we have

$f(x) = p(x)q(x) + r(x), \tag{3}$

for unique $q(x), r(x) \in \Bbb F[x]$ with either $r(x) = 0$ or $\deg r(x) < \deg p(x)$.  Then evaluating (3) at $x = A$,

$f(A) = p(A)q(A) + r(A) = 0 \cdot q(A) + r(A) = r(A), \tag{4}$

since by Cayley-Hamilton $p(A) = 0$.  This shows that every $f(A) \in \Bbb F[A]$ may in fact be expresssed as a ploynomial of degree at most $n - 1$ in $A$; thus $I$, $A$, $A^2$, $\dots$, $ A^{n - 1}$ span $W$, so $\dim W \le n$ over $\Bbb F$.  ***QED.***

Finally, if $A = 0$, $W = \text{span} (I)$, so $\dim W = 1$.